# nvd3 - multiBarHorizontalChart - sum is > 100%

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm using angular-nvd3 and I need to present some horizontal bars, each with a count and percentage. Problem is that the sum of the percentages is sometimes 101%. For example:
[image: example problematic chart]
There are solutions to the 101% problem - for example substract 1 from one of the percent values if it's 101%. The count can stay the same (so the first bar will be `1 (16%)`).
But nvd3 works with a function that receives the bar value and needs to return the string that will be presented, which makes it harder to work out a preprocessing solution.
Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Could you add another significant figure e.g. 66.7% instead of 67%?

Comment: No, I prefer to have integers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this:

So you have to store index of current value, because **valueFormat** does not provide index by it self

```
var valueFormatIndex = 0;

var data = [{values: [ ... ] }];

var config = {

  ...,

  valueFormat: function(d, index){

    valueFormatIndex = valueFormatIndex + 1;

       // if its a last value we should round to lowest

       if(data[0].values.length == valueFormatIndex) {
          return Math.floor(d)
       }

       return Math.ceil(d) // otherwise return round to top
   },

   ... 

}
```

JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/aqLL65tn/)